# Pygame: ImportError: libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, pygame, sdl, cx-freeze

The game is running fine from source code. When I used cx_Freeze to compile the binary file on the Linux I got into error on the second machine:

```
~/tmp/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7 $ ./rungame
/home/local/tmp/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7/library.zip/lib/MenuItem.py:13:   RuntimeWarning: use font: libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
(ImportError: libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
File "rungame.py", line 10, in <module>
File "/lib/gameloop.py", line 13, in <module>
File "/lib/settings.py", line 10, in <module>
File "/lib/menuitem.py", line 13, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 74, in __getattr__
NotImplementedError: font module not available
(ImportError: libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

On the machine where I compile the binary it runs fine. Could someone advice me.

Answer (score 19):

Run this : `sudo apt-get install libsdl-ttf2.0-0`

Comment: This does not work for me. `libsdl-ttf2.0-0` is already installed

Comment: import pygame.mixer had an issue for me, so this did the trick: sudo apt-get install libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0

Comment: @YanickRochon, I had the same issue as you (in that `libsdl-ttf2.0-0` was already installed).  This finally did the trick for me:  `sudo apt-get install python3-sdl2`